# vector de dimensión desconocida con memoria dinámica (en c)

Tags: c, array, archivo, manejo-de-memoria

El **programa consiste** en que yo tengo un archivo que contiene un vector de enteros,pero no se cuantas componentes tiene, usando dimensionamiento dinámico malloc,realloc,free, etc tengo que conseguir la cantidad de componentes que este posee y crear un vector que las contenga. sin desperdiciar memoria.

El **problema esta en el while**, Yo lo probé con un archivo de 5 enteros {1,2,3,4,5} para ver como funcionaba. *En dicho ciclo el contador cuenta 6 componentes en lugar 5* y luego obtengo vectores con 6 componentes cuando en realidad son 5. Yo trate de usar el fseek para controlar la variable de archivo pero no encuentro el error y no cambiaron los resultados. Me gustaría saber como hacer para que cuente bien las componentes y no arrastrar esa componente demás.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#define in 1
main()
{
   int i,j=1,c,pos,*v,*p;
   FILE*arch;
   arch=fopen("vector.dat","r");
   if(arch==NULL)
   {
      perror("El archivo no se pudo abrir\n");
      return -1;
   }
   v=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
   c=fread(v,sizeof(int),in,arch);
   if(c!=in)                       //con esto contemplo la salvedad que el archivo este 'vacio'
   {
      v=NULL;
   }
   else
   {
      while((c==in)&&(0==fseek(arch,sizeof(int),SEEK_CUR)))
      {  
       fseek(arch,-sizeof(int),SEEK_CUR);
       j++; 
       v=(int*)realloc((void*)v,j*sizeof(int));
       c=fread(v+j-1,sizeof(int),in,arch);
       printf("*%d\n",j);
       }

   }
   pos=j-1; //encuentro cuantas posiciones efectivas va a tener mi vector
   p=(int*)realloc((void*)v,pos*sizeof(int));

   p=v;


  //imprimo los valores para ver como salieron
  for(i=0;i<pos+1;i++)
  {
     printf("%d\n",*(p+i));
  } 

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: > Tengo un archivo que contiene un vector de enteros

En qué formato?

Comment: Es un archivo sencillo de se llama vector.dat y el ususrio ingresa valores y luego  lo creo con un fwrite, no se bien que formato tiene la verdad.

Comment: No entiendo como puedes pretender datos de un archivo si no conoces el formato en que están grabados esos datos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No tiene mucho sentido intentar leer datos de un archivo si no tienes en claro en qué formato están grabados.

A falta de ese conocimiento (repito: indispensable) supondré que el archivo contiene `n` enteros grabados en formato binario, ocupando cada uno el tamaño de un `int` en la misma plataforma. [*]

En tal caso, no hace falta leer el archivo completo para obtener `n`, basta con primero preguntar por el tamaño del archivo (puede hacerse con `stat` o, ya que necesitamos abrir el archivo, con `fseek`+`ftell`. Tampoco hace falta un while para leer, podemos hacer un solo `fread`. 
Por ejemplo:

```
int readFile(const char * file) {
  int ret, n, i;
  int * v;
  FILE * arch = fopen(file, "rb");
  if (arch == NULL) {
    perror("El archivo no se pudo abrir\n");
    return -1;
  }
  ret = fseek(arch, 0, SEEK_END); // nos posicionamos al final del archivo
  if (ret != 0) {
    perror("Error en Fseek end\n");
    fclose(arch);
    return -2;
  }
  // ftell nos da la posicion final, es decir cantidad de bytes del archivo
  n = (int)(ftell(arch) / sizeof(int)); // n= cantidad de elementos
  ret = fseek(arch, 0, SEEK_SET);  // volvemos al comienzo del archivo
  if (ret != 0) {
    perror("Error en Fseek set\n");
    fclose(arch);
    return -3;
  }
  if (n == 0) {
    puts("archivo no contiene elementos");
  } else {
    v = (int * ) malloc(sizeof(int) * n); // alocamos buffer
    ret = (int) fread(v, sizeof(int), n, arch); // leemos n enteros
    if (ret != n) {
      puts("error en lectura");
    } else {
      printf("leidos %d enteros\n", n);
    }

  }
  fclose(arch);
  return 0;
}
```

[*] Notar que en general esta no es una buena estrategia, porque el tamaño de un int puede variar entre plataformas - el archivo entonces no sería portable.

Comment: SI investigue y es un archivo binario. Tenes razón con lo de la potabilidad pero suponiendo que la función sizeof siga siendo valida esto podría funcionar genéricamente. Gracias respondiste mi pregunta, me hubiera gustado resolverlo sin el fseek o el ftell pero funciona perfecto igual. Gracias

Comment: "esto podría funcionar genéricamente" - solo si los dos ambientes (el que escribió con fwrite y el que lee con fread) coinciden en el resultado de `sizeof(int)` (4 bytes típicamente, pero no necesariamente) y en la endianess https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: Podes usar stat (al menos en Linux) para obtener el tamaño del archivo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236/how-do-you-determine-the-size-of-a-file-in-c
Hacerlo de otra manera, leyendo de a un entero (o bloque de enteros) y reallocando el buffer es también posible, pero más engorroso (y lento)

Comment: SI eso es cierto es mas rápido y eficiente. yo lo "hice " así, pero si haces el seguimiento del ciclo crea una componente demás ese era básicamente el problema.